# The method compare is undefined for the type ASSIGNRES

Tags: java, collections, compiler-errors, comparator

In my main class how do I give arguments to the `compare` method? Because is asking in object inputs.
It shows me a error:

> The method compare(String, String) is undefined for the type ASSIGNRES;

```
package com.jspiders.Collection;

public class SStudent
{  
    int id;  
    String name;  
    int marks;  

    SStudent(int id,String name,int marks)
    {  

        this.id=id;  
        this.name=name;  
        this.marks=marks;  
    }  
} 

package com.jspiders.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Id implements Comparator
{

    public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)
    {  
        Student s1=(Student)o1;  
        Student s2=(Student)o2;  

        if(s1.id==s2.id)  
            return 0;  
        else if(s1.id>s2.id)  
            return 1;  
        else  
            return -1;  
    }  
}

package com.jspiders.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Name implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object o3,Object o4)
    {  
        Student s3=(Student)o3;  
        Student s4=(Student)o4;  

        return s3.name.compareTo(s4.name);  
    }  
}

package com.jspiders.Collection;

public class Marks
{

    public int compare(Object o5,Object o6)
    {  
        Student s5=(Student)o5;  
        Student s6=(Student)o6;  

        if(s5.marks==s6.marks)  
            return 0;  
        else if(s5.marks>s6.marks)  
            return 1;  
        else  
            return -1;  
    }  
}  

package com.jspiders.Collection;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASSIGNRES 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        /*While(true)
        {
            System.out.println("create id");
            System.out.println("create  name");
            System.out.println("create marks");
            System.out.println("enter the choice");*/
            int choice=sc.nextInt();
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:System.out.println("enter the id no");
                       int idd=sc.nextInt();
                       int idd1=sc.nextInt();
                       Object ans=(int)idd;
                       Object ans1=(int)idd1;
                       compare( ans, ans1);
                       break;

                case 2:System.out.println("enter the name");
                       String name1=sc.next();
                       String name2=sc.next();
                       compare(name1,name2);
                       break;
                case 3:System.out.println("enter the marks");
                       int marks1=sc.nextInt();
                       int marks2=sc.nextInt();
                       compare(marks1,marks2);
                       break;           

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error says it all: there is no method `compare(String, String)` defined within `ASSIGNRES`. If you try to move one of the above defined `compare(Object, Object)` to `ASSIGNRES`, you will end up with some `ClassCastException` since you cannot cast an `Integer` to `Student`.

Comment: so for overcome that what i have to do?

Comment: What do you compare in case 2 and 3? Should it use objects - and if so what their type?

Comment: to know who get the highest marks.

Comment: there is no compare method in your code that works with a pair of integers... marks are integers. what do you want to compare?

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `Comparator` subclasses but not actually using them.

```
                   String name1=sc.next();
                   String name2=sc.next();
                   compare(name1,name2);
```

I assume you mean to call the `compare` method in `Name`, like so:

```
                   Name nameComparator = new Name();
                   Student student1 = new Student(0, sc.next(), 0);
                   Student student2 = new Student(0, sc.next(), 0);
                   nameComparator.compare(student1,student2);
```

This would return which student is greater based on the value of their `name` field.

The `Comparator` subclasses you have take `Student` instances and compare them based on a specific field. You can't call them with the field value directly, you'll have to create instances of `Student` to compare.

Answer (score 0):

When using a method `compare()` inside `main` method of the `ASSIGNRES` class, the compiler will look for that method in the `ASSIGNRES` class (it does not find it there, thus the error).

Looking at your code, I am *guessing* what you want is:

1. Gather data for a single `Student` (like `int ans`, `String name` and `int mark`).
2. Create a `Student` objects(s)
3. Compare `Student` objects using `Student::compare` method

Comment: for compare method it asking obj type inputs for that how i convert int to object type in mainclass.

Comment: You should implement those methods in the following way: `public int compare(Student s1, Student s2)` or (not a good idea) pass `Student` objects as `Object` and cast them to `Student` inside `compare()`